# Why is this specific file not being copied over when publishing?

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, publish, syncfusion, visual-studio-publish

Publishing my azure function from VS 2022, I have a bunch of these in my .csproj:

```
...
<None Update="QtBinariesWindows\Qt5WebChannel.dll">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="QtBinariesWindows\Qt5WebKit.dll">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="QtBinariesWindows\Qt5WebKitWidgets.dll">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="QtBinariesWindows\Qt5Widgets.dll">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="QtBinariesWindows\ssleay32.dll">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
...
```

All of which seem to work fine, and I can see those in app service editor in `bin`:

[image]

But for some reason, this file never gets copied over:

```
<None Update="QtBinariesWindows\Syncfusion.WebKitWrapper">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

I can also see that some empty folders are created at `wwwroot` which match the folder structure of `QtBinariesWindows`, but these do include the `WebKitWrapper` file:

[image]

I've tried simply copying the file from `wwwroot` to `bin`, but I just keep getting these errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reported problem occurs due to the Qtbinaries files not being copied properly. We have faced a similar issue on our end, and it is related to a problem with the Azure SDK.

Please try the conversion with the latest version and follow all the steps mentioned in the UG documentation linked below. Specifically, in step 7, the three (libeay32.dll,libssl32.dll and ssleay32.dll) files are only included. Additionally, you need to include all the QTBinaries files and set the "Copy if newer" option for these files.

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/convert-html-to-pdf/convert-html-to-pdf-in-azure-functions-windows.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.